# POO, Problema para entender la composición versus herencia

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

La teoría enseña que, la "composición" no es derivar una clase de otra, sino inyectarle un objeto que sea una instancia de la clase que necesita. La clase guarda ese objeto internamente y a partir de ahí ya puede usarlo con tranquilidad.
Intento hacerlo en este ejemplo, y no acabo de conseguir hacerlo bien..

```
# creamos la clase Cuenta
class Cuenta:
    # inicializamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self,titular,cantidad):
        self.titular=titular
        self.cantidad=cantidad
 
    # imprimimos los datos
    def imprimir(self):
        print("Titular: ",self.titular)
        print("Cantidad: ", self.cantidad) 

#****************************************************************
        
# creamos la clase CajaAhorro
# esta clase hereda atributos de la clase Cuenta
class CajaAhorro():
    # iniciamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self,titular,cantidad, cuenta):
        self.cuenta = cuenta
 
    # imprimimos los datos de la cuenta
    def imprimir_datos_cuenta(self):
        print("Cuenta de caja de ahorros")
        super().imprimir()

# *****************************************************************

# creamos la clase PlazoFijo
# esta clase también hereda atributos de la clase Cuenta
class PlazoFijo():
    # inicializamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self,titular,cantidad,plazo,interes, caja_ahorro):
        self.caja_ahorro = caja_ahorro
        self.plazo=plazo
        self.interes=interes 
 
    # calculamos la ganancia
    def ganancia(self):
        ganancia=self.cantidad*self.interes/100
        print("El importe de interés es: ",ganancia)
 
 
    # imprimimos los resultados
    def imprimir(self):
        print("Cuenta a plazo fijo")
        super().imprimir()
        print("Plazo disponible en días: ",self.plazo)
        print("Interés: ",self.interes)
        self.ganancia()
 
 
# bloque principal
cuenta = CajaAhorro("Manuel",5000)
caja_ahorro = CajaAhorro(cuenta)
plazo_fijo = PlazoFijo(caja_ahorro)

plazo_fijo.imprimir_datos_cuenta()
```

Me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2c3c3943cb45> in <module>
     52 
     53 # bloque principal
---> 54 cuenta = CajaAhorro("Manuel",5000)
     55 caja_ahorro = CajaAhorro(cuenta)
     56 plazo_fijo = PlazoFijo(caja_ahorro)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cuenta'
```

Agradeceré ayuda para aclarar y fijar este concepto.

Comment: La clase `PlazoFijo` no deriva de `Cuenta`. En el `PlazoFijo.__init__` no llamas a `super`. `cuenta=CajaAhorro` necesita una cuenta que no has creado aun (`plazo_fijo`). `CajaAhorro.__init__` tiene parametros no necesita ni ocupa. `CajaAhorro` probablemente deba ser un contenedor de cuentas.

Comment: Voy a eliminarla para reformularla completamente con otro script más claro.

Comment: Mejor que no. Es un ejemplo interesante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examinemos el modelo de datos primero.

Una Caja de Ahorro contiene depósitos de diversos tipos a nombre de diversos titulares. El modelo correcto contiene tres clases: Caja de Ahorro, Depósito y Títular, ya que una persona puede tener varios depósitos y la Caja contiene depósitos de muchas personas.

**Clase Titular**

La clase títular es la más fácil. En la vida real habría que incluir datos como su DNI, dirección, etc.

```
# Titulares
class Titular:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Nombre: {self.nombre}"
```

Importante: no se imprime dentro de las clases. Lo que se hace es retornar un string que se puede usar para imprimir, o enviar por email, etc. Por eso definimos la función `__str__` para todas las clases.

Cuando escribes `print(algo)`, lo que Python hace es buscar el método `__str__` del objeto `algo`, llamarlo para obtener un string que luego se imprimirá.

**Clase Cuenta**

La clase Cuenta debe incluir todos los métodos que se vayan a usar en las clases derivadas; por esa razón inclui el método `ganancia`, pues toda cuenta tiene una ganancia, aunque sea cero.

```
# creamos la clase Cuenta
class Cuenta:
    # inicializamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self, titular, cantidad):
        self.titular = titular
        self.cantidad = cantidad

    def ganancia(self):
        return 0

    # imprimimos los datos
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{str(self.titular)}\n    Cantidad: {self.cantidad}"
```

**Clase PlazoFijo**

Esta clase deriva de cuenta, y lo que hace es modelar un depósito a plazo fijo con un cierto interés.

```
# creamos la clase PlazoFijo
# esta clase también hereda atributos de la clase Cuenta
class PlazoFijo(Cuenta):
    # inicializamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self, titular, cantidad, plazo, interes):
        super().__init__(titular, cantidad)
        self.plazo = plazo
        self.interes = interes

        # calculamos la ganancia

    def ganancia(self):
        ganancia = self.cantidad * self.interes / 100
        return ganancia

    # imprimimos los resultados
    def __str__(self):
        return f"""
    Cuenta a plazo fijo 
    {super().__str__()}
    Plazo disponible en días: {self.plazo}
    Interés: {self.interes}
    Ganancia: {self.ganancia()}
    """
```

**Clase CajaAhorro**

Esta clase es un contenedor de cuentas (depósitos realmente). Lo único que necesitamos es un nombre para la caja.

Como la clase es un contenedor de cuentas, agregamos el método `add` para agregar una nueva cuenta.

```
class CajaAhorro():
    # iniciamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.cuentas = []

    def add(self, cuenta):
        self.cuentas.append(cuenta)

    def __str__(self):
        st = [f"Caja Ahorro {self.nombre}"]
        st.extend([str(x) for x in self.cuentas])
        return "\n".join(st)
```

**Demo**

Veamos como funciona todo cuando Manuel decide tomar dos depósitos a plazo:

```
# Titulares
class Titular:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Nombre: {self.nombre}"

# creamos la clase Cuenta
class Cuenta:
    # inicializamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self, titular, cantidad):
        self.titular = titular
        self.cantidad = cantidad

    def ganancia(self):
        return 0

    # imprimimos los datos
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{str(self.titular)}\n    Cantidad: {self.cantidad}"

# creamos la clase PlazoFijo
# esta clase también hereda atributos de la clase Cuenta
class PlazoFijo(Cuenta):
    # inicializamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self, titular, cantidad, plazo, interes):
        super().__init__(titular, cantidad)
        self.plazo = plazo
        self.interes = interes

        # calculamos la ganancia

    def ganancia(self):
        ganancia = self.cantidad * self.interes / 100
        return ganancia

    # imprimimos los resultados
    def __str__(self):
        return f"""
    Cuenta a plazo fijo 
    {super().__str__()}
    Plazo disponible en días: {self.plazo}
    Interés: {self.interes}
    Ganancia: {self.ganancia()}
    """

# creamos la clase CajaAhorro, una colección de cuentas
class CajaAhorro():
    # iniciamos los atributos de la clase
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.cuentas = []

    def add(self, cuenta):
        self.cuentas.append(cuenta)

    def __str__(self):
        st = [f"Caja Ahorro {self.nombre}"]
        st.extend([str(x) for x in self.cuentas])
        return "\n".join(st)

titular = Titular("Manuel")
plazo_fijo = PlazoFijo(titular, 5000, 60, 1)
plazo_fijo2 = PlazoFijo(titular, 1000, 90, 1.1)
caja_ahorro = CajaAhorro("La Preferida")
caja_ahorro.add(plazo_fijo)
caja_ahorro.add(plazo_fijo2)
print(caja_ahorro)
```

produce

```
Caja Ahorro La Preferida

    Cuenta a plazo fijo 
    Nombre: Manuel
    Cantidad: 5000
    Plazo disponible en días: 60
    Interés: 1
    Ganancia: 50.0
    

    Cuenta a plazo fijo 
    Nombre: Manuel
    Cantidad: 1000
    Plazo disponible en días: 90
    Interés: 1.1
    Ganancia: 11.0
```

**Edición: Composición/Herencia**

La clase `CuentaAhorro` es esencialmente una lista (*composición*) de objetos de clase `Cuenta`. La clase `CuentaAhorro` no hereda ni duplica ningún método de la clase `list` usada para guardar las cuentas.

La clase `Cuenta` ilustra tanto composición (incorpora un objeto `Titular`) como herencia; tiene como subclase a `CuentaFija`.

Cada técnica tiene su aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por la detallada explicación. No acabo de ver en tu ejemplo  la inyección  de objetos como instancias de la clase que los necesita.  El objeto de mi preunta es entender la composición.

Comment: @efueyo. Agregue una explicación dentro de la respuesta.